# What's the Kirby Diagram of a universal $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology, open-problems

> What's the Kirby diagram of a universal $\mathbb{R}^4$?

**Background**

Define $\mathcal{R}$ as the set of smoothings of $\mathbb{R}^4$. For two oriented elements $R_1$, $R_2$ in $\mathcal{R}$ we can define their *end sum* $R_1 \natural R_2$ if we are given two proper embeddings $\gamma_i : [0, \infty) \rightarrow R_i$.

We remove a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma_i((0, \infty))$ from each $R_i$ and glue the resulting $\mathbb{R}^3$ boundaries together respecting orientations. The result is the *end sum* $R_1 \natural R_2$ of $R_1$ and $R_2$. As $\gamma_i$ is unique up to ambient isotopy, $R_1 \natural R_2$ is well defined up to diffeomorphism.

In ["A universal smoothing of four-space"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214440258) Freedman and Taylor proved the existence of an element $U \in \mathcal{R}$ such that for any $R \in \mathcal{R}$ the *end sum* $U \natural R$ is diffeomorphic to $U$. This $U$ is the universal $\mathbb{R}^4$.

**Foreground**

In ["An invariant of smooth 4-manifolds"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9712292) Taylor defines an invariant $\gamma(R) \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty \}$ for $R \in \mathcal{R}$. Taylor defines $\gamma(R)$ to be $sup_K \{ min_X\{ \frac{1}{2} b_2(X) \} \}$, where $K$ ranges over compact $4$-manifolds smoothly embedding in $R$ and $X$ ranges over closed, spin $4$-manifolds with signature $0$ in which $K$ smoothly embeds. (Actually, Taylor defines $\gamma$ for all smooth $4$-manifolds, but we don't need this detail here.)

Taylor goes on to prove that if $R \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\gamma(R) > 0$, then any handle decomposition of $R$ has infinitely many three handles.

In ["4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus"](http://tinyurl.com/6766kyq) Stipsicz and Gompf prove, see page 376, that $\gamma(U) = \infty$. Thus, any Kirby Diagram of $U$ must have infinitely many three handles.

**Question**

What's the Kirby diagram of a such a $U$?

Comment: Gompf probably knows the answer to this.

Comment: Waiting for G̶o̶d̶o̶t̶ Gompf.

Comment: Godot never showed up, but Gompf did, and it seems as if this is an open problem.

Answer (score 26):

I would also like to know the answer to that. As far as I know, it is still a difficult, unsolved problem. The bit about 3-handles is a clue, but I haven't found any way to make use of it.

Comment: Welcome to MO!!

Comment: Wow, welcome to MO, and thanks for the answer. I wasn't aware that there was still no progress on the Kirby diagram of universal $\mathbb{R}^4$.